# how to encrypt id in flask jinja2 template

Tags: templates, flask, encryption, jinja2

I am accepting a recordset from the python file and using a for loop displaying the records in flask jinja template. For the edit button, i need to encrypt the id. How to call the encryption function in template?

```
<tbody>
{% for record in records %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ loop.index }}</td>
    <td>{{ record[1] }}</td>
    <td>{{ record[2] }}</td>
    <td> 
        <a href="{{url_for('edit_country' ,id=record[0])|encryptdata}}" class="label bg-green" >Edit</a> |
        <a href="{{url_for('view_country',id=record[0])}}" class="label bg-red"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete?');" >Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

Generically, register the encryption function as a filter

```
from jinja2 import Environment

def encryptdata(data):
    return data.upper()

env = Environment()
env.filters['encryptdata'] = encryptdata
```

Since you are using flask, you would need to just decorate the filter with app.template_filter

```
@app.template_filter('encryptdata')
def encryptdata(data):
    return data.upper()
```

Flask documentation for [filters](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#registering-filters).